# node-red system power change event trigger/listner

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, node-red

I have been searching high and low for two days now but cant find a solution for my problem, maybe I am just not using the right "words" when I search.

Anyway, I need a eventlistener for when my monitor goes into power saving mode.
I have the function in EventGhost (built in) but I am moving over to Node-Red.

Not that it matters but I need it to send a signal to turn off the lights when the monitor isn't on and back on of course.

Running Node-Red on a Windows 10 machine (while I test everything out) Probably going to use a Raspberry Pi 3 when I am done.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: This is going to end up being 2 totally different solutions for Window and Linux on the Raspberry Pi

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but if I get everything running on Windows I might as well keep it on my main windows machine that runs 24/7.

Linux and Raspberry Pi 3 will be my second choise.